# cannot convert from 'BillingSystem.Presentation.MasterLogin' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

Tags: c#, forms

i have windows form name called "Master Login"

```
public partial class MasterLogin : UserControl
```

when i passed this form into "program.cs", there is error shows like

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)' has
>   some invalid arguments

my program.cs code below

```
using BillingSystem.Presentation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BillingSystem.Reports;


namespace BillingSystem
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MasterLogin()); //usercontrol ---Error here

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: User control cannot be started as an application. You can put that control on form (let's call it `MasterLoginForm`)and then call `Application.Run(new MasterLoginForm());`

Comment: You need a form, not a usercontrol, to start the application.

Comment: Usercontrols exist in forms, applications start forms. Add a form, add your usercontrol into the form, start the form.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a user control in a WinForms application, as a User Control is a control that is hosted by the Form.

That's why `Application.Run` will not allow you to pass a `UserControl` parameter (hence your compiler error), as it will only run a WinForm.

A *form* is a window that can be displayed.

A *user control* is a reusable part of a form. It is useful when you want to repeat the same or a similar control set in multiple forms, or create a control that is non existent.

You have to add your user control to a form and show this form. If you don't need to reuse your user control, you can also add its contents directly to the form (e.g if the control is just a textbox and a label).

Comment: @artman41: Thanks for the edit, I removed the code part though, because it won't be enough to just create a form and add the UC. The form would need to be resized, maybe the border style changed etc. Better do that in the designer.